# Batch script for set env. variable startup OC4J and remove env. variable

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, oc4j

on local computer are installed an Oracle client (11.2.0) and an OC4J Server (Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0)  (build 090727.2000.36696)), both of them are using the `ORACLE_HOME` enviroment variable so I need to set `ORACLE_HOME` pointing to server folder only when server starts

I'm trying to generate batch file that must do:

1. Set enviroment variable `ORACLE_HOME`
2. Start up OC4J server
3. Unset `ORACLE_HOME` variable

I'm trying with this script but the third statement never runs.

```
call setx -m ORACLE_HOME "C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350" 
call C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350\bin\oc4j -start 
call REG delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /F /V ORACLE_HOME
```

All of this commands works fine executing individually. But, on the same batch script the Start up OC4J "never" ends. Any  idea how can i do this works?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `start "" "C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350\bin\oc4j" -start` if `oc4j` stands for `oc4j.exe`. However, make yourself clear [difference `setx` vs. `set` commands](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file to start the Oracle server just needs the following 2 lines:

```
set "ORACLE_HOME=C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350"
C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350\bin\oc4j.exe -start
```

That's it if `oc4j.exe` is not a console application and therefore command processor immediately continues processing the batch file after starting `oc4j.exe` resulting in closing command process.

Otherwise use:

```
set "ORACLE_HOME=C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350"
start "Oracle Server" C:\Servers\oc4j_extended_101350\bin\oc4j.exe -start
```

Why this works?

Windows creates automatically a copy of the entire environment table of current process for the new process on creating a new process.

For the command process executing the batch file `ORACLE_HOME` is set in its environment table as specified in the batch file.

On starting the Oracle server **this** environment table is copied by Windows for the Oracle server including `ORACLE_HOME` as currently defined. What is defined in Windows registry does not matter and is not taken into account. The Oracle server does not see if there is also `ORACLE_HOME` set at all and if so with which value for parent processes or other processes running parallel.

A simple example to demonstrate environment table management by Windows.

1. Open a command prompt window and enter `set x=Hello`.
2. Type `set x` and you see `x=Hello`.
3. Execute `start` resulting in opening a second command prompt window.
4. Type in this second command prompt window `set x` and you get displayed also `x=Hello`.
5. Switch back to first command prompt window and run `set x=Hi`.
6. Type in this first command prompt window `set x` and you see `x=Hi`.
7. Switch again to second command window, type `set x` and you still see `set x=Hello`.

   This second command process has got a copy of first command process. So what is changed now in the environment table of first command process is not visible for second command process.
8. Execute in second command window `set x=Bye` and verify it with `set x`.
9. Switch back to first command window and enter `set x`.

   It is still output `x=Hi` because also the parent process does not get back what the child process modifies in its copy of the environment table.
10. Switch to second command window and enter `set path=` to delete environment variable **PATH** from environment table of this process.
11. Execute once more `start` to open from second command window a third command window.
12. Enter `set path` and you get displayed just

    ```
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
    ```

What happened with system **PATH**?

System **PATH** as well as user account related **PATH** are still set in Windows registry and build together **PATH** for new processes started from desktop Explorer process. But in the environment tables of second and third command process there is no environment variable **PATH** anymore. Those two processes must work now without environment variable **PATH**. Of course for the first command process and all other running processes **PATH** still exists in their environment tables.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful info, as @JosefZ told the command `set` is the key for do this. You are right about the Windows registry when using `set` instead of `setx`.